# MySQL count query for one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, one-to-many

I have two tables: "member" and "question". Each member can ask more than one question.

I want to retrieve the count of members who have been asked more than 3 questions

My query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  q.question_id, COUNT( q.question_id ) AS question_id_count
FROM member m

inner join question q on m.member_id = q.member_id

GROUP BY m.member_id
HAVING (
COUNT( q.question_id ) >3
)
```

What can I do to improve this query? Thank you

Comment: What does it do? What doesn't it do? What's wrong with it? Please provide more information.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the number of members who asked more than 3 questions or the number of questions asked per members that asked more than 3 questions ?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that they're selecting `q.question_id` but grouping by `m.member_id`.  Probably want to select `m.member_id` instead.

Comment: i want to retrieve number of member asked more than thre question

Comment: @osamajetawe check my answer below, i think its `memberID` that you count

Answer (score 2):

this is incorrect.

If you're groupying by member, you should show member then !

the `distinct` is unnecesary, it will show only one time each member (unless you have repeated members!)

Considering this comment:

> Do you want to retrieve the number of members who asked more than 3
>   questions or the number of questions asked per members that asked more
>   than 3 questions ?

the first option will be

```
select count(*) from 
(SELECT m.member_id 
    FROM member m
    inner join question q on m.member_id = q.member_id
    GROUP BY m.member_id
    HAVING COUNT(q.question_id) >3) T
```

The second option will be

```
SELECT m.member_id, COUNT( q.question_id ) AS question_id_count
FROM member m
inner join question q on m.member_id = q.member_id
GROUP BY m.member_id
HAVING COUNT(q.question_id) >3
```

Comment: @osamajetawe if the answer was what you need, you should tick it as correct (and also upvote!). This or the other one, the more that help you,  and first of two. You can upvote both, but only tick as correct one

Answer (score 0):

based on your statement `i want to retrieve count of member whose asked` **`more than 3 question`**, join the tables and group them by `memberID`.

```
SELECT  a.member_id, count(b.member_id) totalQuestion
FROM    member a
        INNER JOIN question b
            ON a.member_id = b.member_id
GROUP BY a.member_id
HAVING count(b.member_id) > 3
```

as you an see  on this condition, `ON a.member_id = b.member_id`, it links the two tables via `memberID` (*you can freely change the columnName to the name that existed on your table.*)